# pySpark DataFrames Aggregation Functions with SciPy

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark

I've tried a few different scenario's to try and use Spark's 1.3 DataFrames to handle things like sciPy kurtosis or numpy std. Here is the example code but it just hangs on a 10x10 dataset (10 rows with 10 columns). I've tried:

```
print df.groupBy().agg(kurtosis(df.offer_id)).collect()

print df.agg(kurtosis(df.offer_ID)).collect()
```

But this works no problem:

```
print df.agg(F.min(df.offer_id), F.min(df.decision_id)).collect()
```

My guess is because F is: `from pyspark.sql import functions as F` is a sql function programmed in. How would I use dataframes to do things like kurtosis on the dataset?

This also just hangs:

```
print df.map(kurtosis(df.offer_id)).collect()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sadly Spark SQL's current UDF support for Python UDFs is a bit lacking. I've been looking at trying to add some UDFs in Scala and have them callable from Python for a project I'm working on so I did a quick proof of concept using kurtosis as the UDAF to implement. The branch currently lives at https://github.com/holdenk/sparklingpandas/tree/add-kurtosis-support

The first step is defining our UDAF in Scala - this probably is less than ideal but here is an implementation:

```
object functions {
  def kurtosis(e: Column): Column = new Column(Kurtosis(EvilSqlTools.getExpr(e)))
}

case class Kurtosis(child: Expression) extends AggregateExpression {
  def this() = this(null)

  override def children = child :: Nil
  override def nullable: Boolean = true
  override def dataType: DataType = DoubleType
  override def toString: String = s"Kurtosis($child)"
  override def newInstance() =  new KurtosisFunction(child, this)
}

case class KurtosisFunction(child: Expression, base: AggregateExpression) extends AggregateFunction {
  def this() = this(null, null)

  var data = scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.empty[Any]
  override def update(input: Row): Unit = {
    data += child.eval(input)
  }

  // This function seems shaaady
  // TODO: Do something more reasonable
  private def toDouble(x: Any): Double = {
    x match {
      case x: NumericType => EvilSqlTools.toDouble(x.asInstanceOf[NumericType])
      case x: Long => x.toDouble
      case x: Int => x.toDouble
      case x: Double => x
    }
  }
  override def eval(input: Row): Any = {
    if (data.isEmpty) {
      println("No data???")
      null
    } else {
      val inputAsDoubles = data.toList.map(toDouble)
      println("computing on input "+inputAsDoubles)
      val inputArray = inputAsDoubles.toArray
      val apacheKurtosis = new ApacheKurtosis()
      val result = apacheKurtosis.evaluate(inputArray, 0, inputArray.size)
      println("result "+result)
      Cast(Literal(result), DoubleType).eval(null)
    }
  }
}
```

We then can use similar logic as used in Spark SQL's functions.py implementation:

```
"""Our magic extend functions. Here lies dragons and a sleepy holden."""
from py4j.java_collections import ListConverter

from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql.dataframe import Column, _to_java_column

__all__ = []
def _create_function(name, doc=""):
    """ Create a function for aggregator by name"""
    def _(col):
        sc = SparkContext._active_spark_context
        jc = getattr(sc._jvm.com.sparklingpandas.functions, name)(col._jc if isinstance(col, Column) else col)
        return Column(jc)
    _.__name__ = name
    _.__doc__ = doc
    return _

_functions = {
    'kurtosis': 'Calculate the kurtosis, maybe!',
}


for _name, _doc in _functions.items():
    globals()[_name] = _create_function(_name, _doc)
del _name, _doc
__all__ += _functions.keys()
__all__.sort()
```

And then we can go ahead and call it as a UDAF like so:

```
from sparklingpandas.custom_functions import *
import random
input = range(1,6) + range(1,6) + range(1,6) + range(1,6) + range(1,6) + range(1,6)
df1 = sqlContext.createDataFrame(sc.parallelize(input)\
                                    .map(lambda i: Row(single=i, rand= random.randint(0,100000))))
df1.collect()
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
x = df1.groupBy(df1.single).agg(F.min(df1.rand))
x.collect()
j = df1.groupBy(df1.single).agg(kurtosis(df1.rand))
j.collect()
```

Comment: I don't think the UDF solution is working becuase when I do the following:  kert = udf(lambda x: kurtosis(x), FloatType())   print df.select(kert(df.offer_id)).collect()  does not work because it is passing in each value separately. You can't do an .agg with it so I am trying to think of another way.

Comment: Thats true, I actually work on Sparkling Pandas as a side project and this kind of interested me so I started some work to implement support for this there. I'll update my answer to have the details.

Comment: Updated (its a lot of code mostly because we need to do some stuff on the Scala side + the Python side).

Comment: What is EvilSqlTools?

Comment: @theMadKing - its an object that I created inside org.apache.spark to access the internals (you can see it in the PR).